# Expected value of a random variable conditional to its absolute value

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be an integrable real-valued random variable with a strictly positive probability density function $f$ on $\mathbb R$. What is $\mathbb E \left(X \middle \vert \left|X\right| \right)$?

To me, it is obvious that conditionally on $\left|X\right| = x$, $X$ has a discrete distribution with 2 possible values : $-x$ and $x$. As for the probability of each outcome, I have a strong intuition that $\mathbb P \left(X = x \middle \vert \left|X\right| = x \right) = \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(-x)}$. After all, that defines a probability and it is worth $\frac{1}{2}$ for symmetric distributions.

However, I have absolutely no idea how to justify it... Is it even correct ?

Comment: Your answer cannot be correct. If $X$ has  symmetric distribution then $E(X||X|)=0$.

Comment: Also when you have a density function $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x$ so you should not use the arguments you use for discrete random variables.

Comment: Are you doing measure-theoretic probability?

Comment: @grand_chat Yes, measure-theoretic probability is fine. But is the measure not discrete in this case?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I do not see why you say that. For a symmetric random variable, there is no more chance to be $x$ than $-x$ so you should have a null expectation. Moreover, once you know $|X|$, you *almost* know $X$ up to its sign, so I do not see how the conditional distribution of $X$ knowing $|X|$ could have a density.

Comment: To speak in measure theory, I think that $\mathbb P \left( \left\{X \in (-\infty, -x) \cup (-x, x) \cup (x, +\infty) \right\} \middle \vert |X| = x \right) = 0$, so the measure has to assign weights to ${x}$ and ${-x}$ only.

Comment: @siou0107 Yes, the measure is discrete. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, but you are using $x$ on both sides of your conditioning, which renders your answer ambiguous and confusing. Instead, write $Y:=|X|$ and use a different variable $y$ for the value of $Y$.

Your reasoning is: given $Y=y$, there are two possible values for $X$, namely $y$ and $-y$, with probabilities proportional to $f(y)$ and $f(-y)$ respectively. Since the two probabilities must sum to unity, the probabilities should be $\frac{f(y)}{f(y)+f(-y)}$ and $\frac{f(-y)}{f(y)+f(-y)}$ respectively.

The expected value of $X$ given $Y=y$ is then a straightforward calculation of the expectation of a discrete random variable:
$$E(X\mid Y=y) = y\frac{f(y)}{f(y)+f(-y)}+(-y)\frac{f(-y)}{f(y)+f(-y)}=y\frac{f(y) -f(-y)}{f(y)+f(-y)}$$
and therefore your candidate conditional expectation is
$$E(X\mid Y)=Y\frac{f(Y) -f(-Y)}{f(Y)+f(-Y)}.
$$
Call the RHS $h(Y)$. To prove $h(Y)$ is indeed the conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$, simply use the definition, which requires you to verify:

1. $h(Y)$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable.
2. $E(h(Y)I_A)=E(XI_A)$ for every $A\in\sigma(Y)$ [i.e., $h(Y)$ integrates over sets in $\sigma(Y)$ the same as $X$ does].

Step 1 is immediate. For step 2 it's enough to check this for any $A$ of the form $\{|X|\le c\}$, since such sets generate $\sigma(Y)$. You now have an exercise in integral calculus.